# Adding HTML string to DOMDocument in PHP

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

I have a DOMDocument object and I want to manipulate text nodes and return them to the object as a HTML string. For example:

```
$dom=new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<html><body>This is [b]BBC[/b]</body></html>');

// $node is a text node
$html=parseBBC($node->nodeValue);
$frag=$dom->createDocumentFragment();
$frag->appendXML($html);
$node->parentNode->replaceChild($frag,$node);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Expected output:

```
<html><body>This is <b>BBC</b></body></html>
```

Actual output:

```
empty string
```

**Edit:**

```
$dom=new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<html><body>This is[br]BBC</body></html>');
$xpath=new DOMXPath($dom);

$r=$xpath->query('//text()');
foreach($r as $el){
  $str=trim(str_replace('[br]',"\n",$el->nodeValue));
  $str='<p>'.preg_replace('/(\n|\r)+/','</p><p>',$str).'</p>';
  $frag=$dom->createDocumentFragment();
  $frag->appendXML($str);
  $el->parentNode->replaceChild($frag,$el);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: What does `parseBBC` do? And in particular, what does it return which ends up in `$html`?

Comment: It just returns a string with HTML. For example: `This is <b>BBC</b>`

Comment: Pls provide all code necessary to understand what's going on.

Comment: Check the edited section. I removed the `parseBBC()` function. I thought it was obvious that it parses BBCode and returns HTML.

Comment: You have a comment that says `// $node is a text node` but you don't actually show any code where `$node` comes from. Either this isn't an actual tested example of the problem, or you have a "White Page of Doom" and need to [check error logs or adjust your error display settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772851#12772851)

Comment: I added `echo $dom->saveHTML();die;` after each line, and the problem lies in `$el->parentNode->replaceChild($frag,$el);`

Comment: The second example works fine - outputs `<html><body><p>This is</p><p>BBC</p></body></html>`.